# How would I approach sorting something like this

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
 1
  14
    141
        141010
        141020
        141030
        141040
        141050
        141060
    142
        142010
        142020
    144
        1440
          144010
          144020
          144030
          144040
```

Currently for a school project I have to make an array based on similar numbers.

Any number that has 1-2-3-4 numbers as length can have children.

However I can't figure how to solve this programmatically as when the number 1440 in this scenario doesn't exist 144010~ has to sort itself under 144 and if 144 doesn't exist it goes below 14 but stay under the numbers that start with 142.

Any help on how I would approach this problem would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

Some code I've tried:

```
 Public Class DataSet
        Public Property one As Integer
        Public Property two As New List(Of Two)
        Public Property three As New List(Of three)
        Public Property four As New List(Of four)
    End Class

    Public Class Two
        Public Property two As Integer
        Public Property three As New List(Of three)
    End Class

    Public Class three
        Public Property three As Integer
        Public Property four As New List(Of four)
    End Class

    Public Class four
        Public Property four As Integer
        Public Property six As New List(Of String)
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim ds As New List(Of DataSet)
        Dim one As New List(Of String)
        Dim two As New List(Of String)
        Dim three As New List(Of String)
        Dim three_found As New List(Of String)
        Dim four As New List(Of String)
        Dim six As New List(Of String)
        Dim words() As String = File.ReadAllLines("Numbers.txt")
        For Each w In words
            Dim length = w.Length
            Dim number = Convert.ToInt32(w)
            Select Case length
                Case 1
                    one.Add(w)
                Case 2
                    two.Add(w)
                Case 3
                    three.Add(w)
                Case 4
                    four.Add(w)
                Case 6
                    six.Add(w)
            End Select
        Next

        For Each i In one
            Dim dso As New DataSet
            dso.one = i
            For Each t In two
                If t.StartsWith(i.ToString()) Then
                    Dim newtwo = New Two
                    newtwo.two = t
                    dso.two.Add(newtwo)
                End If
                For Each th In three
                    If th.StartsWith(i) Then
                        three_found.Add(th)
                        Dim twoc = th.Substring(0, 2)
                        If twoc.StartsWith(t) Then
                            Dim threec As New three
                            threec.three = th
                            Dim threef = dso.two.Where(Function(w) w.two = twoc).FirstOrDefault()
                            If threef IsNot Nothing Then
                                threef.three.Add(threec)
                            Else
                                dso.three.Add(threec)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next        
            ds.Add(dso)
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: `Any number that has 1-2-3-4 numbers as length` Numbers do not have a length, so I am guessing you are really using strings?  The post is generally very unclear

Comment: What is your final output? Is it just that order (in for example an array) or do you actually want a hierarchical structure as your final result?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes i'm sorry English is not my first language, indeed every "number" is a string currently

Comment: Hello @Chris I'm not sure how to explain it but when for example 141 doesn't exist the 141010-141060 have to stay under 14 but all the numbers that then start with 142 have to be after the 141 ones

Comment: Check TreeView.

Comment: @Glenn: I'm not asking about the rules, I'm asking about the structure you want this data to be in. eg do you want an array or integers? a list of strings? A set of nested dictionaries? If you wrote some code showing what you've tried it would give us a lot of details that seems to be lacking from your question./

Comment: Im guessing because of the structure it would have to be a list of strings @Chris I've added some code to this post that i've tried however i cant seem to figure out on how to get it so where if for example the string with length of 3 characters doesn't exist all the strings with 4 or more characters go under the string simular with 2 characters but then if that one doesn't exist it goes under the string simular with 1 character etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do that without using a Treeview (why wouldn't you I don't know):

```
void Main()
{
    string values = @"1
  14
    141
        141010
        141020
        141030
        141040
        141050
        141060
    142
        142010
        142020
    144
       1440
          144010
          144020
          144030
          144040
    145020
    145030
    145010
          ";

    int myValue;
// Splitting and converting to a collection of integers ordered by randomly
// just to show initial order doesn't matter
    var myData = values.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(s => int.TryParse(s.Trim(), out myValue) ? myValue : -1)
        .Where(n => n != -1)
        .OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid());

// We have the collection. Sort it "directory" style
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    var list = myData.Select(d => d.ToString());
    foreach (var v in myData)
    {
        myList.Add(Fullpath(v.ToString(), list));
    }
    var ordered = myList.OrderBy(l => l);
// Write out the result intended
    foreach (var element in ordered)
    {
        var levels = element.Count(e => e == '/');
        var value = levels > 0 ? element.Remove(0, element.LastIndexOf('/') + 1) : element;
        Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(levels, '\t') + value);
    }
}

// Get the full path for a value with ancestors
// ie: 1/14/1440/144010 is the full path for 144010
private string Fullpath(string key, IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= key.Length; i++)
    {
        if (list.Any(v => key.Substring(0, i) == v))
        {
            paths.Add(key.Substring(0, i));
        }
    }
    return string.Join("/", paths);
}
```

Note that values are shuffled before starting to sort and this is what you get:

```
1
  14
    141
      141010
      141020
      141030
      141040
      141050
      141060
    142
      142010
      142020
    144
      1440
        144010
        144020
        144030
        144040
    145010
    145020
    145030
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said before check Treeview. It already does this type of hierarchy for you.

This code is in C# but you can easily convert to VB (manually or by using an online converter like Telerik's and editing a bit):

```
void Main()
{
    string values = @"1
  14
    141
        141010
        141020
        141030
        141040
        141050
        141060
    142
        142010
        142020
    144
       1440
          144010
          144020
          144030
          144040
    145020
    145030
    145010
          ";

    int myValue;
    var myData = values.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(s => int.TryParse(s.Trim(), out myValue)?myValue:-1)
        .Where(n => n != -1);

    Func<int, IEnumerable<int>, int?> parent = (value, list) =>
    {
        while (value > 0)
        {
            value /= 10;
            if (list.Any(l => l == value))
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    };

    var nodes = myData
        .Select(d => new { d, parentNode = parent(d, myData) })
        .OrderBy(d => d.parentNode)
        .ThenBy(d => d.d);

    TreeView tv = new TreeView();
    foreach (var n in nodes)
    {
        var v = n.d.ToString();
        ((n.parentNode == null)
        ? tv.Nodes
        : tv.Nodes.Find("_" + n.parentNode.ToString(), true).First().Nodes)
        .Add("_" + v, v);
    }

    foreach (TreeNode node in tv.Nodes)
    {
        WriteNode(node, 0);
    }
}

private void WriteNode(TreeNode node, int level)
{
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(level, '\t') + node.Text);
    foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
    {
        WriteNode(n, level + 1);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1
  14
    141
      141010
      141020
      141030
      141040
      141050
      141060
    142
      142010
      142020
    144
      1440
        144010
        144020
        144030
        144040
    145010
    145020
    145030
```

Note: If you want to do without a Treeview, then use a logic like:

- Create a list,
- Loop your values,
- For each value, get the value as a string,
- Loop starting with length towards 0 and get substring, (say value is 144010)
- Check if that substring exists, (you would find 1440)
- If it does prefix your value with that value plus a separator, (1440\144010)
- Now continue the search with new parent (1440),
- Append any "parents" as you find (final would become 1/14/144/1440/144010)
- Add this to the list you have at top.
- Sort your list (because of directory like structure all values would find their place).
- You can dump your values indented by count of your separator + the value after last separator (like the last folder name in a directory structure).

Comment: I'm very sorry to ask this but how would i approach the list part in code as im getting confused by your explanation

Comment: I will add is another answer.

Answer (score 0):

And this is VB version (warning: I don't use VB and don't know it, used Telerik converter and modified slightly to make it work, due to VB.Net lack of literals like "\t" I used 4 spaces to intend - didn't want to add VisualBasic namespace):

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim values As String = <values>
1
  14
    141
        141010
        141020
        141030
        141040
        141050
        141060
    142
        142010
        142020
    144
       1440
          144010
          144020
          144030
          144040
    145020
    145030
    145010
</values>

' Splitting and converting to a collection of integers ordered by randomly
' just to show initial order does not matter
    Dim myValue As Integer
    Dim myData = values _
        .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
        .Select(Function(s) If(Integer.TryParse(s.Trim(), myValue), myValue, -1)) _
        .Where(Function(n) n <> -1) _
        .OrderBy(Function(n) Guid.NewGuid())

' We have the collection. Sort it "directory" style
    Dim myList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim list = myData.Select(Function(d) d.ToString())
    For Each v In myData
        myList.Add(Fullpath(v.ToString(), list))
    Next

' Write out the result intended
    Dim ordered = myList.OrderBy(Function(l) l)
    For Each element In ordered
        Dim levels = element.Count(Function(e) e = "/"c)
        Dim value = If(levels > 0, element.Remove(0, element.LastIndexOf("/"c) + 1), element)
        Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(levels * 4, " ") + value)
    Next
End Sub

' Get the full path for a value with ancestors
' ie: 1/14/1440/144010 is the full path for 144010
Private Function Fullpath(ByVal key As String, ByVal list As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
    Dim paths As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    For i As Integer = 1 To key.Length
        If list.Any(Function(v) key.Substring(0, i) = v) Then
            paths.Add(key.Substring(0, i))
        End If
    Next

    Return String.Join("/", paths)
End Function

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by Refactoring Essentials.
'Twitter: @telerik
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```